Scripting in Blender to create 3 methods of extrude, bend and rotate
I am trying to create 3 methods, I have the extrude and the rotate, but I cannot figure out the bend portion of the script. I need it so that I can systematically bend and extrude to form an object. Its like a wire extruding and then bending in different directions.
I would like it so that the bend moves so that it appears to stay on a specific spot on the wire even after the wire is extruded more.
I have tried a simple deform, but then the extrusion aspect does not work appropriately.
I made a visual example using geometry nodes of what it should look like. Any help at all would be appreciated!




